# Using Jquery to dynamically add an element to my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have followed a tutorial and created some html and Jquery which should dynamically add a new element when the add new button is clicked. However i am testing jsfiddle and it isn't working, i have used the exact same code as used in the tutorial. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/pocockn/P5uPQ/1/

```
$(function() {
        var addDiv = $('#addinput');
        var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

        $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                i++;

                return false;
        });

        $('#remNew').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the [**.live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

So you should replace `live()` with `on()`.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var addDiv = $('#addinput');
    var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

    $('#addNew').on('click', function () {
        $('<p><input type="text" class="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" class="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click','.remNew', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**NOTE:**

- keep in mind that ID's **must** be unique. I changed to class in the code posted here.
- Because you are adding content dynamically the `remNew` must use delegation.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SsVEc/)

Answer (score 1):

live is deprecated

```
$(function() {
        var addDiv = $('#addinput');
        var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

        $('#addNew').click(function() {
                $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                i++;

                return false;
        });
        alert(i);
        $('#remNew').click(function() { 
                if( i > 3 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
$('#addNew').live('click', function() { ...
```

to:

```
$('#addNew').on('click', function() { ...
```